# Create git tree manually from file on Windows (Git Bash)

Tags: windows, git, format, cat

I am following a Git tutorial and I want to create a tree from a file. I use the Git bash on a Windows 10 computer. The file has the following content:

```
100644 blob b7aec520dec0a7516c18eb4c68b64ae1eb9b5a5e file1.txt
100644 blob 4400aae52a27341314f423095846b1f215a7cf08 file2.txt
```

I want to use the command

```
cat ../temp-tree.txt | git mktree
```

to read in the file and to create a tree. After I run the command I get the error

```
fatal: input format error: 100644 blob b7aec520dec0a7516c18eb4c68b64ae1eb9b5a5e file1.txt
```

I assume that is it a problem with the format of the line-endings or something similar, because I think the syntax should be correct

Comment: Is it a (space) or a (tab) just before file name? (should be a tab)

Comment: Thank you very much, it solved the problem!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the record, the exact expected format is

```
<mode>SPACE<type>SPACE<object>TAB<file>
# for example
100644 blob b7aec520dec0a7516c18eb4c68b64ae1eb9b5a5e    file1.txt
```

...so the (space) between object hash and filename in your file should be a (tab).